# GTX 460 (GF104) is faster then GT 740m (GK107), why?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm running a gSLIC segmentation algorithm on my GT 740m (GK107) and the segmentation takes **93ms**.
From the gSLIC report http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~carl/papers/gSLIC_report.pdf I know that they were using GTX 460 (GF104) and their segmentation takes **13ms**.

The GK107 architecture has **384 cuda cores** in two SMXs and the GF104 has **336 cuda cores** in seven SMs.
Depends on the algorithm (shared memory occupancy) I calculated that my GK107 able to run 1280 active threads on one SMX, what's 2x1280 = **2560** active threads overall and the GF104 able to run 1280 active threads on one SM, what's 7x1280 = **8960** active threads overall. But the GF104 has less cuda cores then GK107 so it should process less threads concurrently, shouldn't it? Or the GF104 because of the number of SMs has smaller on cost?

What could be the reason of these results?

Comment: memory speed, memory capactiy, PCI-E express speed.. etc.. take your pick Other considerations are CUDA API support

Comment: The GT740m is a mobile chipset, whereas the GTX460 isn't. The mobile versions usually have lower clock speeds, memory bandwidths, etc. than their non-mobile counterparts, even though they might be named similarly.

Comment: I think sonicwave has hit the nail on head here quite typically the mobile versions, even later model versions will not outperform an older generation desktop version

Comment: Comparison of two CUDA-capable devices goes way beyond the sole number of CUDA cores or number of SMs. You also have to take into account compute capability, clock speeds, etc. The GTX460 is a *much* faster GPU than the GT740M (look at G3D benchmarks, for example) despite being older.

Comment: The [memory bandwidth of GT740m](http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=1247&gid2=690&compare=geforce-gt-740m-vs-geforce-gt-640m) is ~28GB/s, whereas for GTX460 it is [about 4x higher](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-460/specifications).  Without knowing anything about gSLIC, my guess is that it may be memory bound.

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted to hear :)
http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-460-vs-GeForce-GT-740M

Comment: Btw for example if I have an RGBtoHSV convertion on 640x480 image where the pixels are floats of 4bytes then what is the size of the data what I need to consider in bandwidth? 
I have to consider both the load from global memory and also the store to global memory or only the load?

640x480x4x3 = 3686400 B is the image size, but I have to load it and also store so I have to  consider it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the GF104 has less cuda cores then GK107 so it should process less
>   threads concurrently, shouldn't it?

Number of concurrent threads is not the only metric, especially considering the fact that GTX460 is of Fermi architecture, whereas GT740m is Kepler. How about the speed at which these threads are executed? That's where one of the main differences between Fermi and Kepler lies, you may read more about it in [this article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5699/nvidia-geforce-gtx-680-review/2) which should provide you with necessary insight. Small teaser:

> Because NVIDIA has essentially traded a fewer number of higher clocked
>   units (Fermi) for a larger number of lower clocked units (Kepler), NVIDIA had to go in
>   and double the size of each functional unit inside their SM. Whereas a
>   block of 16 CUDA cores would do when there was a shader clock, now a
>   full 32 CUDA cores are necessary.

Also sonicwave pointed out GT740m is a mobile GPU which, we could say by definition, has narrower bus than desktop GPU, simply because of space limitations (desktop vs laptop). This results into quite significant difference in bandwidth, as Robert Crovella states as well, and therefore in memory heavy applications will GTX460 simply outperform GT740m. At gpuBoss they have a nice GPU compare utility, see [here](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-460-vs-GeForce-GT-740M) for compelete results or below for important points.

> **Reasons to consider the Nvidia GeForce GTX 460**
>
> - Higher effective memory clock speed    3,400 MHz   vs  1,802 MHz   Around 90% higher effective memory clock speed
> - Higher memory bandwidth    108.8 GB/s  vs  28.8 GB/s   More than 3.8x higher memory bandwidth
> - More render output processors  32  vs  16  Twice as many render output processors
> - Wider memory bus   256 bit vs  128 bit 2x wider memory bus
> - More texture mapping units 56  vs  32  24 more texture mapping units